# Cannot Export sharedpreferences to CSV Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, export-to-csv, internal-storage

Okay So this is an activity class where I am trying to export my sharedPreferences that are saved to a CSV file. This does not work. What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly write the sharedPreferences items to a CSV file?

```
        import java.io.FileWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.Map;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class Admin extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

            Button btViewContacts = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewContacts);
            Button btDeleteContacts = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteContacts);
            Button btExportCSV  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExportCSV);
            final Context context = this;
            final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);





                btViewContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        startActivity(new Intent(Admin.this, Contacts.class));
                    }
                });

                    btDeleteContacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //DISPLAY ALERT DIALOG
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);                         //show an alertDialog when user selects delete radio button and clicks process, prompt to confirm
                            //set title
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("DELETE ALL CONTACTS?");
                            //set dialog message
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ALL acquired contact info?")
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                //no button
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { //if user selects no, close dialog
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        //if clicked this will close the dialog and do nothing.
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                })
                                //yes button
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //if user selects yes, clear the shared preferences and display confirmation message when deleted.

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        //if this button is clicked it will erase the values in memory

                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                        editor.clear();
                                        editor.commit();
                                        //displays toast message confirming deletion of race info
                                        Toast.makeText(Admin.this, "Contact Info Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }

                    });

                    Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPref.getAll();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                        Log.d("TAG", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
                    }



                    btExportCSV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                             generateCsvFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                        }
                    });


        }

        private void generateCsvFile(String sFileName)
           {
            final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                     .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String delimiter = ",";
            try
            {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

                writer.append("First Name");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("Last Name");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("Email");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("Phone");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("Address");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("City");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("State");
                writer.append(',');
                writer.append("Zip");
                writer.append('\n');

                Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPref.getAll();
                for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                    Map<String,?> all = sharedPref.getAll();
                    Iterator it = all.entrySet().iterator();
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    if (pairs.getKey().toString().startsWith("contactid_")) {
                        String strContact = sharedPref.getString((String)pairs.getKey(), "");
                        String[] data = TextUtils.split(strContact, delimiter);
                        writer.write(strContact);
                        writer.append('\n');

                } 


                    Toast.makeText(Admin.this, "ContAcq's Exported to .CSV.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                //generate whatever data you want

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } 
                }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }

    }
```

Comment: can you please check the value of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() in your code.

Comment: not sure what I did. I tried putting in sdcard/download at first and it told me I shouldnt hard code that in eclipse. I believe that it is my root folder in the sdcard

Comment: can you try by appending a file name to that?. it looks like the string variable is a path to a directory than to a file

Comment: Yes I tried that to file labeled Backup.csv. No luck